# how to fill TListView runtime without PrototypeBindSource

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

I have studied:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_LiveBindings_to_Populate_a_ListView_(iOS_and_Android)

How to fill a `TListView` type component in runtime? I'd use the text and bitmap field.

Answer (score 1):

I do it this way:

```
item := ChanelsListView.Items.Add;
item.Text := Chanel.Name;
item.Detail := Chanel.ProgTypeName;
item.Bitmap.Assign(Chanel.Logo);
item.Tag := Chanel.Cod;
```